# Why is the renderValue function not being called? I want to give the Select dropdown a placeholder

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The "renderValue" function is not working. I want to give the Select dropdown a custom placeholder but it doesn't work.

Here's the Select component:

```
<Select
            className={classNames({ error: !!error })}
            labelId={name}
            id={name}
            value={multiple ? value || [] : value}
            disabled={disabled}
            multiple={multiple}
            onChange={(event) => {
              onChange(event);
              if (handleChange) handleChange(event.target);
            }}
            renderValue={(selected) => {
              if (!selected) {
                return <em>Placeholder</em>;
              }
            }}
            MenuProps={menuProps}
            endAdornment={
              showCrossIcon && (
                <IconButton
                  sx={{ visibility: value ? 'visible' : 'hidden', position: 'absolute', right: '20px', zIndex: '1' }}
                  disableRipple
                  onClick={() => {
                    onChange('');
                  }}
                >
                  <CrossIcon />
                </IconButton>
              )
            }
            sx={{ paddingRight: '0px' }}
          >
            {options.map((item) => {
              const isLabelValueOption =
                typeof item === 'object' && item.hasOwnProperty('label') && item.hasOwnProperty('value');
              const optionLabel = isLabelValueOption ? item.label : item;
              const optionValue = isLabelValueOption ? item.value : item;
              return (
                <MenuItem key={optionLabel} value={optionValue} className="menu-item">
                  <div data-testid="menu-items" className="multi-select">
                    <OverflowText sx={{ margin: '0px' }}>{optionLabel}</OverflowText>
                  </div>
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
```

It's a reusable component. To give more context, here's where it coming from:

```
<SelectFormField
            data-testid="timeGrain"
            fieldType="Select"
            fieldSize="medium"
            tableSelect={true}
            name="timeGrain"
            label="Time Grain"
            control={control}
            options={timeGrainOptionsList}
            defaultValue={R.pathOr('P1D', ['time', 'timeGrain', 'defaultValue'], configurationTemplate)}
            required={R.pathOr(false, ['time', 'timeGrain', 'required'], configurationTemplate)}
          />
```

and then:

```
export const SelectFormField: React.FC<SelectProps & AdditionalFormFieldProps> = (props) => {
  const { name, defaultValue, control } = props;
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <SelectField {...props} value={value} onChange={onChange} error={error} />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

I have followed the MUI Select component documentation it seems to be the right way to give it a placeholder. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is in the `renderValue` function. As per your code, the render value would only return `Placeholder` text when there is no selected option. But in the case when there is a selected option, it will return nothing. So what you want to do is update the renderValue function as below:

```
renderValue={(selected) => {
   if (!selected || selected.length === 0) {
     return <em>Placeholder</em>;
   } else if(Array.isArray(selected){
     return selected.join(', ');
   } else {
     return selected
   }
 }}
```

Comment: it still doesnt work.

Comment: i want it so that when there is no selected option, it shows a placeholder value.

Comment: I have tried this:
```
renderValue={(selected: string | string[]) => {
              if (!selected || selected.length === 0) {
                return <em>Placeholder</em>;
              } else {
                return selected;
              }
            }}
```
Can't use selected.join because it gives a type error.

Comment: And it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try the above code, it can handle the type error

Answer (score 0):

You can only use it when the native prop is false (default).

Signature:
function(value: any) => ReactNode
value: The value provided to the component.

- Is `<em></em>` a react node? Maybe it needs wrapping in brackets? Is your value supposed to be `MenuItem`

Comment: Actually I want to pass a placeholder prop from the parent component.